# TopSpeed ODBC Driver for Python 3.x

Tags: python, odbc, unixodbc

Is there a way to make the old school TopSpeed (.TPS) database work in Python?

Basically, I want to convert a data aggregation C# app that turns various data from AS/400 DB2 and some .TPS files from a mapped drive, into a Python web app. The DB2 part has already been taken care of.

I've been thinking that this can be done via PyODBC & SQLalchemy, but I don't know anything about this database type. What is the connection string? How can connect a mapped drive into a Ubuntu container? Is there a Linux driver for this or does unixODBC work? I have no idea.

Anything can help. Thank you.

[image: .TPS file sample]

Here is the connection string used for the C# app.

[image: connection string used for the C# app]

Comment: `DRIVER={Topspeed ODBC Driver (Read-Only)}` looks like a valid ODBC driver name. What happens if you try to use it with pyodbc?

Comment: I tried to list `pydodbc.drivers()` on my Windows machine with TopSpeed driver installed, but it does not show any `Topspeed ODBC Driver (Read-Only)` driver name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question for the future me and others.

The **TopSpeed Driver is only available on 16-bit and 32-bit Windows**. Using the 32bit Python and 32bit Driver should work.

Unfortunately, based on my extensive research, there is no Linux driver available, and the driver is NOT FREE. I will not put the driver's website here for legal reasons, though a quick Google search should show you the way to buy it.

Furthermore, there is no dialect for sqlalchemy yet, and I don't think it will.

For my purpose I'm using `pyodbc` to connect shown below:

```
TPS_CONNECTION_STRING = (
    'Driver={Topspeed ODBC Driver (Read-Only)};'
    'DBQ=X:\\;'
    'Extension=tps;'
)

TPS_DB_CONNECTION =pyodbc.connect(TPS_CONNECTION_STRING, autocommit=True)
```

Where `DBQ` is the directory or location of the `.tps` files. Then connect and execute queries with

```
TPS_DB_CURSOR = TPS_DB_CONNECTION.cursor()
res = TPS_DB_CURSOR.execute('SELECT * FROM FILE')
TPS_DB_CURSOR.close()
```

As we are using a `pyodbc` connection, we can also use the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html#) `read_sql` function to get the results back into a DataFrame immediately. Just pass the connection object; in this example, it will be `TPS_DB_CONNECTION`